# Finitistic dimension conjeture for $A^{op} $ implies the strong Nakayama conjecture for A

Tags: representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, projective-module

I have some trouble with some detail in the proof of the following theorem. Assume that the Finitistic dimension conjecture is true for $ A^{op} $  that is $ sup\{ proj.dim(M) \vert M \in mod(A^{op}) ~and~ proj.dim(M) < \infty \} $, then for each $ M \in mod(A) $ there is a i with $ Ext ^i(M, _AA) \neq 0 $.

The proofs works by contradiction. For a module M pick a minimal projective resolution $(P_i)_{i \geq 0}$ and apply the functor $Hom_A(-,_AA)$ to obtain (by assumption) the exact sequence
$$0 \to Hom_A(P_0, _AA)\to _{f_0} Hom_A(P_1,_AA) \to _{f_1} ... $$
Now by left exactness of the contravariant Hom functor this gives a projective resolution of $Cok(f_i)$ for all i, in particular this resolution is finite and by assumption on fin.dim of $A^{op}$ modules the projective dimension of all these modules is bounded by some m. Now there is the last step I do not understand: now we want to argue that $f_0$ is a split monomorphism and this should be done by considering $ Cok(f_m) $, afterwards by duality this should translate to M being zero. I suspect that the statement follows from looking at the Ext terms of a suitable module, but I sadly couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just missed the obvious. 
The key point is that the projective dimension is bounded and thus choosing m larger than the Finitistic dimension of $A^{op}$ will yield that at some point (at most after m steps) all the morphisms in the resolution will split, so in particular $f_0 $ will be a split monomorphism.